# Does netty io version 4.x support log4j2 version?

Tags: java, netty

We have successfully moved our project from Netty 3.x to Netty 4.x. However, we are planning to move our project from log4j to log4j2.

First of all, does Netty 4.x support log4j2?  If so, can you offer any suggestions or link explaining what to do?

Comment: fixed grammar, removed noninformative message

Answer (score 1):

Netty supports `log4j2` from version `4.0.37.Final` onwards.
See [issue link.](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/3095)

However you have to add an additional line of code (see first line below `InternalLoggerFactory.setDe...`):

```
InternalLoggerFactory.setDefaultFactory(Log4J2LoggerFactory.INSTANCE);
ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
serverBootstrap.group(parentGroup, childGroup)
    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
    .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
    ...
```

Then add the Logger entry as follows to your `log4j2.xml`. Example:

```
<Loggers>
  ...
  <Logger name="io.netty" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
  </Logger>
  ...
</Loggers>
```